# emit final with tumbling window

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

Use Case  :  Get the message from the KSQL stream (visitor_topic1) to push in to new kafka topic (final_visitor) every 1 minutes.

```
 > CREATE TABLE final_visitors_per_min
WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='final_visitor', KEY_FORMAT='JSON', PARTITIONS = 3, REPLICAS = 3)
    AS
SELECT 
>  id,
>  visitorName
>  FROM vister_List_stream
>  WINDOW TUMBLING (SIZE 1 MINUTE)
>  GROUP BY id EMIT CHANGES;
```

so I created one table and get message from stream (visitor_topic1) with tumbling window with size as 1 MINUTES and emit change .

With Emit CHANGES -  in the topic2 am getting immediately when the topic 1 received message not wait 1 minutes to send .

with Final . but not emit  any message topic2

any one have the suggestions ? where the problem want to receive the message every 1 minute delay ..

Comment: Hi. I've exactly the same problem. Did you find any solution for that ?

Comment: No i am not found any .. dropped